# Configure TextBlock Properties from Resource File in UWP

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I have been working around to set `Font Size`, `Margin`, `FontWeight` and `Text` Properties of `TextBlock` from Resources file. It only works with `Text` properties, the remaining properties is not working. Am I following wrong direction?

In resource file I have below

[image: Resources.resw File]
In XAML file, I have using below

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
   <TextBlock x:Uid="MyApp" />
   <TextBlock Text="about" Style="{StaticResource PageTitle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Is it possible to set `TextBlock` properties from `Resource File`?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but how did you add this Resource File? It works fine by me. I set resource file like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MpbL1.png), and my test result is like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O0cBa.png). Could you please share a sample or block of code, so can I reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thank you, I have added my resource file pic. As I mentioned the text property works fine, but others don't

Comment: Tried again, still it works fine by me. Could you please create a new  UWP project and try this again?